# Rspecs for model and before_create methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec-stories

I have model name: UserApplicationPatient.
That model having two associations:

```
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :customer

  before_create :set_defaults

  private

  def set_defaults
    self.enrol_date_and_time = Time.now.utc
    self.pap = '1'
    self.flg = '1'
    self.patient_num = "hos_#{patient_id}"
  end
```

Factories of UserApplicationPatient

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user_application_patient do
    association :patient
    association :customer
    before(:create) do |user_application_patient, evaluator|
      FactoryBot.create(:patient)
      FactoryBot.create(:customer)
    end
  end
end
```

Model spec:

```
 require 'spec_helper'

 describe UserApplicationPatient do
   describe "required attributes" do
   let!(:user_application_patient) { described_class.create }

   it "return an error with all required attributes" do
    expect(user_application_patient.errors.messages).to eq(
     { patient:         ["must exist"],
       customer:        ["must exist"]
     },
    )
  end

 end
end
```

This is the first time I am writing specs of models.
Could someone please tell me how to write specs for set_defaults before_create methods and factories what I have written is correct or not.

Comment: https://dev.to/vasily/rspec-rails-how-to-test-callbacks-326e

Comment: You never use your factory.

Comment: Where does patient_id come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test your defaults are set, create a user and test if the defaults are set.

- You definitely don't want to use `let!`, there's no need to create the object until you need it.
- Since we're testing `create` there's no use for a `let` here at all.
- How do we test Time.now? We can [freeze time](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-freeze_time)!
- I assume `patient_id` should be `patient.id`.

Here's a first pass.

```
it 'will set default attributes on create' do
  freeze_time do
    # Time will be the same everywhere in this block.

    uap = create(:user_application_patient)

    expect(uap).to have_attributes(
      enrol_date_and_time: Time.now.utc,
      pap: '1',
      flg: '1',
      patient_num: "hos_#{uap.patient.id}"
    )
  end
end

it 'will not override existing attributes' do
  uap_attributes = {
    enrol_date_and_time: 2.days.ago,
    pap: '23',
    flg: '42',
    patient_num: "hos_1234"
  }
  uap = create(:user_application_patient, **uap_attributes)

  expect(uap).to have_attributes(**uap_attributes)
end
```

These will probably fail.

- Defaults are set *after* validation has taken place.
- Existing attributes are overwritten.
- What is `patient_id`?

We can move setting defaults to [before validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html). That way the object can pass validation, and we can also see the object's attributes before writing it to the database.

We can fix set_defaults so it doesn't override existing attributes.

`Time.now` should not be used, it is not aware of time zones. [Use `Time.current`](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones). And there's no reason to pass in UTC, the database will store times as UTC and Rails will convert for you.

```
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :customer

  before_validation :set_defaults

  private

  def set_defaults
    self.enrol_date_and_time ||= Time.current
    self.pap ||= '1'
    self.flg ||= '1'
    self.patient_num ||= "hos_#{patient.id}"
  end
```

We can also make your factory a bit more flexible.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user_application_patient do
    association :patient, strategy: :create
    association :customer, strategy: :create
  end
end
```

This way, the patient and customer will be created regardless whether you `build(:user_application_patient)` or `create(:user_application_patient)`. This is necessary for user_application_patient to be able to reference its patient.id.

In general, don't do things at create time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting default values in the before_create hook, I will recommend validating it like this

```
describe UserApplicationPatient do
   describe "required attributes" do
   
   let!(:user_application_patient) { described_class.create }

    it "return an error with all required attributes" do
      # it will validate if your default values are populating when you are creating a new object
      expect(user_application_patient.pap).to eq('1')
    end

  end
end
```